# JavaScript - Log into website and read data

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, https, web-crawler

#### Intro

Hey everyone,

So I'm a student attending GCU, and I'm building a chrome extension for the school website to re-theme it. While I'm at it, I wanted to add in a notification system so students can see when assignments are due and announcements are, well, announced.

The issue is that the school LMS does not have an API or notifications system. The data is spread all throughout the website, which is a pain in the neck to have to browse through every day.

Is there a way to use JavaScript to search these pages without opening a browser or bogging things down for the user?

#### Requirements

I would need a JavaScript file that can fire from a chrome extension, connect to the school, login to the school website, read data from specific pages, and then return it to the user.

The process would be something like this:

1. Navigate to website
2. Login
3. Read off each class from sidebar
4. Begin going to each class's announcement, assignment, and message pages.
5. Return data somehow

#### Specifically the Answer I'm looking for

I'm mainly just looking for a "yes or no" response. I'm not exactly sure if this is a security breach, or if it is something JavaScript or a Google Chrome Extension is capable of.

However, I'm definitely open to any helpful information and advice you might have for this project. I'm pretty sure the GPA of the entire university will go up if I can get this notification script to work...

Thanks for the help!

Jacob

Comment: You should be able to do this with Ajax. You may need to enable [cross-origin HTTP requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) on the school server, which has security implications that need to be addressed.

Comment: I don't have access to the school's security settings. Theoretically, if I did, how would this be done?    - Edit - I mean to say, how would I get around the login page?

Comment: The link in my previous comment discusses this a bit. The actual mechanics of it depend on the server. Again, you may not even need to do this; it's just something to pin down as you start development.

Comment: Yes, from the description, this is possible.